# @ApplicationScoped and JBoss clustering

Tags: cluster-computing, jboss6.x

is an `@ApplicationScoped` resource shared throught all the nodes of a JBoss 6 cluster? Do you have some docs to suggest about? TIA.

Comment: I made some test. Accordingly with [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/clustering-intro.chapt.html#clustering-quickstart-launching) I succesfully create a two node cluster (two JBoss 6 AS running on the same machine) and the application show expected behavior (I shut down a node and given id is still unique ecc.). Then, I successfully create a two node cluster with two JBoss 6 AS running on different machines (192.168.0.4 and 192.168.0.5). Sadly, `@Applicationscoped` resource was not shared. It seem `@Applicationscoped` work on single JVM only. Is that true?

Comment: Are you sure your two nodes in the local cluster run on the same JVM?

Comment: Hello. Yes I am. I run both servers on my computer.

Comment: What `@Applicationscoped` "resource" are we talking about? `@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped` or `@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`? And by the way JBoss cluster nodes never share a JVM, because that would simply be a single node listening on two ports.

Comment: As indicated [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/clustering-intro.chapt.html#clustering-quickstart-launching) I launch my two node cluster:

run.bat -c all -g DocsPartition -u 239.255.100.100 -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 -Djboss.service.binding.set=default
run.bat -c all -g DocsPartition -u 239.255.100.100 -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01

`@ApplicationScoped` is `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`.